# how to create autofac factory for dependency resolution

Tags: c#, design-patterns, ioc-container, autofac, factory

I'm using a IDbcontext to acces my database

```
   public sealed class DbContext : IDbContext
{
    private bool disposed;
    private SqlConnection connection;

    public DbContext(string connectionString)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public IDbConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().Name);

            return connection;
        }
    }

    public IDbTransaction CreateOpenedTransaction()
    {
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            Connection.Open();
        return Connection.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteProcedure<T>(string procedure, dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null)
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        return Dapper.SqlMapper.Query<T>(connection, procedure, param, transaction,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }

    public int ExecuteProcedure(string procedure, dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null)
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        return Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(connection, procedure, param, transaction,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("** Disposing DbContext");

        if (disposed) return;

        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Dispose();
            connection = null;
        }

        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

I have 2 database **"first**" and "**second"**

In the resolution o depenancy of fist, i use

```
 builder.Register<IDbContext>(c =>
          new DbContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["first"].ConnectionString))
          .InstancePerDependency();
```

So i need to add:

```
builder.Register<IDbContext>(c =>
              new DbContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["second"].ConnectionString))

          .InstancePerDependency();
```

I need to create a factory for Dbcontext and Use NamedResolve for with autofac, How can I do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class DbContextFactory
{
    private ILifetimeScope m_RootLifetimeScope;

    public DbContextFactory(ILifetimeScope rootLifetimeScope)
    {
        m_RootLifetimeScope = rootLifetimeScope;
    }

    public IDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        if (logic for selection first dbcontext)
        {
            return m_RootLifetimeScope.ResolveNamed<IDbContext>("first");
        }
        else if (logic for selection second dbcontext)
        {
            return m_RootLifetimeScope.ResolveNamed<IDbContext>("second");
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}

//registration

builder.RegisterType<DbContextFactory>().SingleInstance();

//using

var factory = yourContainer.Resolve<DbContextFactory>();
var context = factory.CreateDbContext();
```